# Javascript open menu on website

Tags: javascript

I feel like my explanation is not precise enough:
I am interessted in a short command line which, pasted into the console of firefox, opens the "help" menu of "www.stackoverflow.com". The button "Tags" on the stackoverflow.com website can be clicked on by

```
document.getElementsById('nav-tags').click()
```

The "help" menu on the top right does not have an Id... is it still possible to open it via javascript and additionally click on the first entry after opening "help"?

## Former Question:

my problem is rather difficult to explain since I am not familiar with javascript. I am trying to press a button from VBA in order to create folders in a MS Sharepoint environment and to change their settings (for example reading/writing rights). While I figured out the first, the latter is quite difficult because I have to navigate through the Sharepoint website. This could be done with VBA "Sendkey" commands but after some testing it seems to be very error-prone. Additionally, a lot of stackoverflow questions are answered with "execscript" as the solution.
So I am trying to break down the task bit by bit (javascript from VBA)...
First step, send the click command from the firefox console:
executing

```java
document.getElementByID('logo').click();
```

in the firefox console on this website https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=asd navigates to the main google website.

In the Sharepoint environment the "relevant" code looks like this:

```php
<ul id="Ribbon.LibraryContextualGroup_lower" class="ms-cui-ct-ul" unselectable="on">
    <li id="Ribbon.Document-title" class="ms-cui-tt ms-cui-ct-first" role="tab" unselectable="on"></li>
    <li id="Ribbon.Library-title" class="ms-cui-tt ms-cui-ct-last" role="tab" unselectable="on">
        <a class="ms-cui-tt-a" onkeydown="if(event != null && event.keyCode == 13){ if(typeof(_ribbon)… = true; _ribbonStartInit('Ribbon.Library',false, event); }" title="Bibliothek" onclick="_ribbonStartInit('Ribbon.Library',false, event);" href="javascript:;" unselectable="on">
                <span class="ms-cui-tt-span" unselectable="on">
                    Bibliothek
                </span>
                <span class="ms-cui-hidden" unselectable="on"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

So I tried:

```java
document.getElementById('Ribbon.library-title').click();
```

and recieved

```
undefined
```

Browsing throught lots of stackoverflow-questions led me to the conclusion that it must have something to do with the unsorted list elements. My guess would be that the classname "ms-cui-tt-a" needs to be in the comandline since it is connected to the "onkeydown" command. But since I am not sure whether I am right and even if I would be, I still dont know how to combine it properly. Thus, any hints are very well appreciated.
Regards, poe

Comment: Are you sure you need "." in your id name? and the id you are trying to call is not spelled correctly. Javascript will need to match the exact string if it is looking for element with particular id.

Comment: Removing the "." in the id name results in a "null" error since it cannot be found. executing "document.getElementById('Ribbon.Library-title');" on the other hand prints the data according to the ID which leads me to believe that its correctly spelled and that the "." is needed.

Comment: Are you doing this in VBA or javascript?

Comment: currently i am trying to open the Tab "library" of the Sharepoint website using javascript and the firefox console. After succeding i will try to take the next step and implement the code to VBA. My understanding was that I need the javascript code in order to use the execscript function from VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no ID which can be used, one needs to create a list of all the elements in question and has to select the correct one either by title or something else, in this case by order. 
the list is being created by the following command

`$ document.getElementsByClassName('icon-help js-help-button');`

since there is only one Element

`$ document.getElementsByClassName('icon-help js-help-button')[0].click();`

will open the menu.

With regard to my former Questions and the Sharepoint 2013 environment

`$ document.getElementsByClassName('ms-cui-tt-span')`

There are 3 entries in the list (starting from 0 to 2)

`$ document.getElementsByClassName('ms-cui-tt-span')[1].click()`

the second Element will be clicked.